# Extend Go Programming Language with C, Converting Data Types

Tags: c, arrays, go, slice

How can I convert data types from c to go and vice-versa?

For example, I have a function that returns an array of integers:

```
char* Test()
{
    char*msg = "Hello, Go";
    return msg;
}
```

How can I convert it to slice or array?

--UPDATE--

In Go file, I can use `C.GoString(C.Test())` to convert the return type to Go String. I'm looking for a complete doc for these functions.

Comment: Please try to make the code you want and we'll help you with specific errors/problems. Your example isn't even valid (or reasonable) C code (you can't return an array like that in C).

Comment: @AskBjørnHansen: actually, you can. The literal will outlive the function.

Comment: `C.GoString` makes a string out of a C string, copying the data. What more is there to say?

Comment: @larsmans When I added the comment the function was defined as `int[] test ()`

Answer (score 7):

You should have a look at http://golang.org/cmd/cgo/ . Here's an example using it http://golang.org/misc/cgo/gmp/gmp.go

Comment: That's fine, but I need some tutorials or documentations, meanwhile I have no time to study source code :|

Comment: where is the doc for functions like C.GoString?